# How many calls I can make to OSM's Nominatim instance?

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, mkreversegeocoder, nominatim

I am developing mobile application which using google maps and I want to find users current address with device latitude and longitude (Reverse geocoding).

Google have some limits and it will charge me once I go beyond it. 
Now I am looking on OpenStreetMap, it is open to use in public. And I can use Reverse geocoding with it.

e.g. http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=20&lon=71&zoom=18

My question is, 
1). Is there any limit to make these calls per day? 
2). Do I need to register somewhere ?
3). Is there any other alternatives available ?

Thnks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the [Nominatim Usage Policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy)

If you exceed the limits given there one of your options is to [run your own instacne](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation)

There are also ready-to-run [Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=nominatim&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&starCount=0&pullCount=0) available on Docker Hub

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Besides runing your own Nominatim instance you can also take a look at [third-party providers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do have a limitation on the service. Check out the page here: [Usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy)

And from Sep 15, 2015. You need to register before you could use the service, check out the page here: [Registration page](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/)

Also, you could install a local nominatim here: [Installation page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Ubuntu.2FDebian)
Check out the github page: [Github page](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim)

Anyway, if it doesn't work, you could try a bunch of different geocoders, like: Pelias from mapzen, Photon, OpenCage Geocoder. Good luck geocoding!

Comment: Thanks for giving other options